# How I retrieve a extensionProperty on B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are trying to work with B2E optional claims … we followed this doc and this to create the extension Claim at B2E, than populate it with some value… and enable it on Token Conf/Manifest. We also setup de XML with the PartnerClaimType but we can’t receive the Claim from B2E. Do you have some tip or idea why we cant receive the claim?

Defaults claims works fine, but optional… we spent at least 2 days with tons of tests… =(

```
Extension Claim
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#applications('XXX9f805-40cb-41af-80ae-c63201919XXX')/extensionProperties",
"value": [
{
"id": "XXX707f9-8cdb-4cfa-996e-59da8512fXXX",
"deletedDateTime": null,
"appDisplayName": "",
"name": "extension_XXXb714c01374c3e89a7c700bbd0eXXX_perfil",
"dataType": "String",
"isSyncedFromOnPremises": false,
"targetObjects": ["User"]
}
]
}

Populated claim from and User
{ "extension_XXXb714c01374c3e89a7c700bbd0eXXX_perfil": "tempinfo",
}

B2E App Manifest
"saml2Token": [
{
"name": "extension_XXXb714c01374c3e89a7c700bbd0eXXX_perfil",
"source": "user",
"essential": false,
"additionalProperties": []
}
]
```

OpenId ClaimProvider

Obs.: we also tried “extension_perfil” and “extn.perfil”

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extensionproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims

Comment: Have you configured AAD as an IdP to AAD B2C and want to parse the extension attribute from the optional claims setup in AAD? It’s not clear at all what you have setup or what your goal is. Be more explicit in your descriptions and provide links to docs you’ve used.

Comment: Hey, Jas, I edited the post, can you review again, please?

Comment: Have you used the auth code flow in POSTman against AAD directly so you can isolate whether the issue is to do with AAD not issuing your optional claim versus AAD B2C not having the correct claim mapping to parse the claim? Try to determine where the issue is by testing against AAD without AAD B2C involved.

Comment: How I can isolate the auth code flow AAD via postman? Can you help me in this? Its my first time

Comment: Follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Comment: Can you review the answer below, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In technical profile `OIDC-ViaVarejo` change

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_perfil" />
```

To

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_perfil" PartnerClaimType="extn.perfil" />
```

Your claims definition should be as follows since AAD is returning an Array:

```xml
<ClaimType Id="extension_perfil">
  <DisplayName>extension_perfil</DisplayName>
  <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
  <UserHelpText>extension_perfil</UserHelpText>
</ClaimType>
```

If you want to display the value to the screen in a textbox, you need to [convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/stringcollection-transformations#getsingleitemfromstringcollection) the `stringCollection` to a `string` (itll just get the first value):

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="ExtractPerfil" TransformationMethod="GetSingleItemFromStringCollection">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_perfil" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="perfil" TransformationClaimType="extractedItem" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Define the claim `perfil`

```xml
<ClaimType Id="perfil">
  <DisplayName>perfil</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
  <UserHelpText>extension_perfil</UserHelpText>
  <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
</ClaimType>
```

Then modify `SelfAsserted-AADVV-PersonalData`:

```xml
...
    </CryptographicKeys>
    <InputClaimsTransformations>
      <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="ExtractPerfil" />
    </InputClaimsTransformations>
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Step" DefaultValue="SelfAsserted-AADVV-PersonalData" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="perfil" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_DataNasc" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Step" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" Required="true" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="perfil" Required="true" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_DataNasc" Required="true" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="DDIBrasil" DefaultValue="+55" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Celular" Required="true" />
    </OutputClaims>
...
```